# How are we cancelling out $dx$ when that isn't mathematically accurate?

Tags: calculus, integration

When we prove the work-energy theorem for a variable force using integration, we have this step:
$$ W = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} {F}  {dx} \ $$
Now, using Newton's second law of motion:
$$ F = ma, $$
we rewrite the equation as:
$$ W = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} {m} {a} {dx} \ $$
And using the chain rule, we write $a(t)$ as:
$$ a(t) = \frac {dv}{dx}\ \cdot \frac {dx}{dt} \ $$
i.e. $$ a(t) = \frac {dv}{dx}\ \cdot v $$
Now, we substitute the value of $a$ in the original integral:
$$ W = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} {m} {\frac {dv}{dx}\ \cdot v } {dx} \ $$
Here is where my problem starts. I've seen in my textbooks and in many websites that they 'cancel out' the $dx$ to get:
$$ W = \int_{v_1}^{v_2} {m} \cdot {v} {dv} $$
However, I've read in maths that cancelling out 'dx' like this isn't rigorous. So why do they do it? And what is the correct alternative?

Comment: It's basically a substitution (i.e. chain rule) where the new variable of integration is velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule is really being applied here; canceling out "$dx$" is just sloppy notational convenience.

$$W = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} {m} {\frac {dv}{dx}\ \cdot v } {dx}= \int_{x_1}^{x_2}  {\frac {d}{dx} \left(\frac{1}{2} mv^2\right) } {dx}=\frac{1}{2}mv(x_2)^2-\frac{1}{2}mv(x_1)^2 =\Delta KE.$$

Comment: Note this is a univariate derivation; it can be extended to multiple dimensions.

Comment: I'm sorry; this may seem silly, but I'm just not in the clear here. How do you go from the first step to the second step—where does the mv^2/2 part come from? Where did the 'v' go?

Comment: @archthegreat $v$ is a function of $x$...applying the chain rule in the second step gives you the first step

Comment: Got it—thanks a lot. And why have you written mv(x_2)^2/2 - mv(x_1)^2/2 in the last step instead of, you know, m(v_2)^2/2-m(v_1)^2/2? Shouldn't the definite integral in the second last step be from v_1 to _v2 instead of x_1 to x_2?

Comment: @archthegreat I write it that way because $v$ is a function of $x$ here (you can of course suppress the dependency by defining $v_i:=v(x_i)$).  As for the integral bounds, notice the variable of integration is $x$ so the bounds are $x$ bounds.  However, I could do a substitution ($u=v(x)$) to change the integral to a $dv$ integral and change the bounds to $v$ bounds. In fact, the method of substitution is really based on the chain rule+FTC. You can see the proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Proof).

Answer (score 1):

In standard analysis that's just some kind of a mnemonic technique. What you are actually using here is that for $v(x)$ its differntial is $dv=\frac{dv}{dx}dx$. Or, more strictly, without mentioning differential forms, you are using the rule of changing variables in a definite integral ($f=mv$): $$\int^{x_2}_{x_1} f(v(x))v'(x)dx=\int^{v(x_2)}_{v(x_1)}f(v)dv $$